# Программа и Аваст

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Вот возник вопрос! Создаю программу даже пустую на C#,и у Avast пишит что программа вредоносная,как исправить?

Comment: NOD32 шлет пламенный привет!

Comment: Лучше без антивируса, чем использовать Avast, код тут не причем.

Comment: и язык не причем тоже, видел аналогичный финт с c++ + mingw недавно, а когда-то давноэтим же грешил каспер, ловя экзешники на выходе борландовской студии (дельфи или плюсы не помню уже)

Comment: Касперский на борландовские плюсы так реагировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть извращений способ. Запустить windows в безопасном режиме. Есть другие способы добавить в исключения, но не чего хорошего не выйдет.

Comment: а почему бы действительно не добавить в исключения?

Answer (score 7):

Замена или удаление антивируса конечно поможет. Но у пользователей Вашей программы можт быть установлен Аваст. Рекомендую написать о проблеме разработчикам антивируса, послав им и свою программу.

Answer (score 2):

Удали Аваст

Comment: И я останусь без Защиты,как это исправить в коде C#,а не удалить антивирусную систему.

Comment: никак, меняй антивирус

Comment: Ставь доктор вэб

Comment: >> И я останусь без Защиты

Будто ты сейчас с ней.

Answer (score 0):

Слышал о том, что Касперский реагирует на ЛЮБОЙ код, написанный на Delphi. Оказывается, в компилятор, предоставляемый с ключём вида: "11111-11111" вшит троян. Возможно, и в вашем случае также?!
Имя вируса, определяемого Авастом задайте в поиске, и почитайте кто он есть такой.

Comment: Вы не совсем правы, у Delphi была проблема, но троян не вшит был и не зависел от ключа, была подмена одного из pas файлов, код вреда не приносил но в тоже время копировал себя во все программы которые писались на delphi а антивирусники реагировали.

Comment: Вы правы, вы более точно выразили мысль, которую я донести не смог. Именно так.

Comment: нету там имени вируса скорее всего, у меня на mingw говорил просто подозрительная программа - типа "нету в базе, но мне не нравится". Он так скорее всего реагирует на исполняемый файл, который генерит другие исполняемые файлы, причем иногда это бывает у всех, я выше уже упомянул что такую же проблему встречал у каспера с борландовскими продуктами (не с зараженной дельфей)